# Can wine made from orange and sweet lime be stored for a long time?

Tags: wine, storage

I am very newbie to this site.

I know that wine can be made from **orange** and **sweet lime**.

But is it storable for a long time ..?

If yes how ..?

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: What is the alcohol content?

Comment: I see from some searching that orange or lime wine is generally home made. You may get a better answer on the Home Brew SE site.

Comment: As Eric commented, the alcohol content is probably the most important factor here. Sufficient alcohol preserves very well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Can wine made from orange and sweet lime be stored for a long time?**

That will depend on several factors. The main factor will be what the alcohol content is in the wine. My personal guess that such wine would be of a lower alcohol content.

The alcohol content is probably the most important factor here. Sufficient alcohol naturally preserves very well.

Also make sure that the are not impurities in the final product.

Do not fear to add **sulfites** to your wine in order to help preserve your wine for a much greater duration of time.

Sulfites are used as a preservative in many food items, not just wine.

> Sulfites such as Campden tablets and sodium metabisulfite make sure your wine does not spoil during the wine making process. After the wine has been made, sulfites help to insure that your wine will keep for many years and not just weeks or months in the wine bottle. Sulfites also help your wine to be free from the effects of oxidation. This is when the color of the wine darkens and the flavor taken on a little bitterness. Adding sulfites to homemade wine is not an absolute necessity, but it only makes sense to do so.
>
> Potassium sorbate on the other hand is a different beast. It should only be used before bottling the wine – if at all. It is required if you are planning on back-sweetening your wine at bottling time. If it is not added along with the sweetening sugar, you stand a very strong chance of experiencing a re-fermentation of your wine while in the bottle. This can eventually result in popping corks and fizzy wine.
>
> There is no reason to add potassium sorbate at any other time than at bottling. In fact, if it is added before the fermentation has completed it will most likely result in a sluggish or stuck fermentation. I would not recommend adding it at bottling time if you are not making a sweet wine. It is not necessary.
>
> If you are making wine from fresh fruit, I always recommend adding sulfite to homemade wine about 24 hours before adding the yeast. Leave the wine must uncovered during this 24 hours so that the sulfite gas may dissipate. Then add the wine yeast as you normally would. Doing this will easily destroy any wild molds, bacteria, etc. that may be coming along with the fruit.
>
> I always recommend that sulfite be added before bottling, as well. This is the dose that keeps the wine fresh and free of oxidation while in the wine bottle. Before fermentation and before bottling are the two times I would never forgo.
>
> I also suggest adding sulfites to wine after the fermentation has completed. This is with the understanding that the wine is going to sit for a while before clearing up. This will keep any airborne contaminants from growing on your wine while clearing.
>
> Adding sulfites to homemade wine is important and highly recommended. It’s like buying insurance for making a wine that doesn’t spoil or oxidize. If you do not add sulfites you can make wine successfully, but most will find it hard for the wine to keep over extended periods of time without refrigeration. - [Adding Sulfites To Homemade Wine](https://blog.homebrewing.org/adding-sulfites-to-homemade-wine/)